# Bash script to add/remove desktop launchers to Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, bash, scripts

I'm trying to write a script to setup my desktop environment after a fresh install.  One thing I can't figure out is how to pin/unpin items to the Unity Launcher from a bash script.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered copying the configuration files?

Comment: Don't know what or where they are?

Comment: They are in your home directory and start with a dot, so are hidden. Type `ls -dF .*` I don't know which you need, there are files for just about every application you run.

Comment: The list of items on the launcher is not in a simple configuration file, or a directory full of files itself.

Comment: It is easy to add launchers but the thing is that in every solution available online, you have to do an ugly restart...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use gsettings:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

Gives you a list of what's on the launcher:

```
['nautilus-home.desktop', '/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome.desktop', 'apps.desktop', 'geany.desktop', 'libreoffice-startcenter.desktop', 'gnome-terminal.desktop', 'gcalctool.desktop', 'Science.desktop', 'gimp.desktop', 'inkscape.desktop', 'ubuntu-software-center.desktop', 'alarm-clock-applet.desktop']
```

so you can do something like this in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
myfile='firefox.desktop'
list=`gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites`
newlist=`echo $list | sed s/]/", '${myfile}']"/`
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "$newlist"
```

I tested and it works to add firefox to the launcher, however the icon doesn't display immediately. You'll have to log out/in or do a `unity --replace` command.

Comment: If you want to change the settings for other users, use `sudo -u username dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "$newlist"`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23849268/2746945

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command:

```
xdg-desktop-menu install --novendor /path/to/app-name.desktop
```

The `app-name.desktop` file would look something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=App Name
Comment=A description of the app
Exec=/path/to/app
TryExec=/path/to/app
Icon=/path/to/app-icon.ico
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=App-Category
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that doesn't pin it on the Unity launcher.

Comment: `unity --replace`?

Comment: While this added it in the um... launcher thingy (Dash home) it did not pin it, even with `unity --replace`. However I could easily pin it after this by dragging it from the dash to the sidebar.